# Compare julian date in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, julian-date

I have a requirement where I have to find out the most recent datetime in julian from list of dates by using XSLT.

If I pass the below XML

Input:

```
<Orders>
<Order>
<OrderNumber>100</OrderNumber>
<Date>116256</Date>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderNumber>101</OrderNumber>
<Date>116256</Date>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderNumber>102</OrderNumber>
<Date>116276</Date>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

Output:

```
<Result>
<Date>116256</Date>
</Result>
```

Please help me with the XSLT.

Thanks
Yatan

Comment: What format are your "dates"? They don't look like anything "julian" to me. And why is 116256 the most recent, and not 116276? -- Also state which version of XSLT  can you use.

Comment: The Julian day 116276 is 7 May 4395 BC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your "dates" are numbers, and that those numbers increase as time goes by, you only have to sort the Orders by Date, descending, and get the Date of the first one:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Orders">
    <Result>
        <xsl:for-each select="Order">
            <xsl:sort select="Date" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="Date"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
   <Date>116276</Date>
</Result>
```

This is not the result you have in your question - but under the assumptions stated above, it is the correct one.